# Write a python script that goes through the links on a page recursively

Tags: python

I'm doing a project for my school in which I would like to compare scam mails. I found this website: http://www.419scam.org/emails/
Now what I would like to do is to save every scam in apart documents then later on I can analyse them.
Here is my code so far:

```
import BeautifulSoup, urllib2

address='http://www.419scam.org/emails/'
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
f = open('test.txt', 'wb')
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

This saves me the whole html file in a text format, now I would like to strip the file and save the content of the html links to the scams:

```
<a href="2011-12/01/index.htm">01</a> 
<a href="2011-12/02/index.htm">02</a> 
<a href="2011-12/03/index.htm">03</a>
```

etc.

If i get that, I would still need to go a step further and open save another href. Any idea how do I do it in one python code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You picked the right tool in BeautifulSoup.  Technically you could do it all do it in one script, but you might want to segment it, because it looks like you'll be dealing with tens of thousands of e-mails, all of which are seperate requests - and that will take a while.

[This page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is gonna help you a lot, but here's just a little code snippet to get you started.  This gets all of the html tags that are index pages for the e-mails, extracts their href links and appends a bit to the front of the url so they can be accessed directly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.419scam.org/emails/"))
tags = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("20......../index\.htm")
links = []
for t in tags:
    links.append("http://www.419scam.org/emails/" + t['href'])
```

're' is a Python's regular expressions module.  In the fifth line, I told BeautifulSoup to find all the tags in the soup whose href attribute match that regular expression.  I chose this regular expression to get only the e-mail index pages rather than all of the href links on that page.  I noticed that the index page links had that pattern for all of their URLs.

Having all the proper 'a' tags, I then looped through them, extracting the string from the href attribute by doing t['href'] and appending the rest of the URL to the front of the string, to get raw string URLs.

Reading through that documentation, you should get an idea of how to expand these techniques to grab the individual e-mails.

Comment: Any idea if we can make it recursive  to more than one level ?

Comment: @NeilGhosh Do you mean scraping a page for links and then scraping the html from all of those links?

Comment: Yes , Basically I was trying to find all the links no matter which page they are in , but in the same website

Comment: Well you have to 'visit' a web page in order to scrape it with Beautiful Soup. For instance, in the above example, you could `urlopen()` every element of `links` and run `BeautifulSoup(...)` on each of those.  This will of course be pretty resource (network) intensive if you are doing this for a lot of pages.

Answer (score 3):

You might also find value in [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) and [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).  Requests is another way to make http requests and lxml is an alternative for parsing xml and html content.

There are many ways to search the html document but you might want to start with [cssselect](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html).

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = 'http://www.419scam.org/emails/'
doc = fromstring(requests.get(url).content)

atags = doc.cssselect('a')

# using .get('href', '') syntax because not all a tags will have an href
hrefs = (a.attrib.get('href', '') for a in atags)
```

Or as suggested in the comments using `.iterlinks()`.  Note that you will still need to filter if you only want 'a' tags.  Either way the .make_links_absolute() call is probably going to be helpful.  It is your homework though, so play around with it.

```
doc.make_links_absolute(base_url=url)

hrefs = (l[2] for l in doc.iterlinks() if l[0].tag == 'a')
```

Next up for you... how to loop through and open all of the individual spam links.

Comment: I would vote +10 if I could, because lxml and requests offers a much more pythonic API than BeautifulSoup and urllib.

Comment: But iterating over the links could be easier done. There is are the methods `make_links_absolute` and `iterlinks` of the `doc` oject.

Comment: @ms4py I could not help but provide an answer with lxml and requests for the same reason ... way more pythonic and enjoyable to use.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

To get all links on the page you could use BeautifulSoup. Take a look at [this page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it can help. It actually tells how to do exactly what you need.

To save all pages, you could do the same as what you do in your current code, but within a loop that would iterate over all links you'll have extracted and stored, say, in a list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [HTML parser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) and specify the type of object you are searching for.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == 'href':
                    print attr[1]

address='http://www.419scam.org/emails/'
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
f = open('test.txt', 'wb')
f.write(html)
f.close()

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(html)
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres a solution using `lxml` + `XPath` and `urllib2` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2 -u
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import cookielib, urllib2
from lxml import etree

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
page = opener.open("http://www.419scam.org/emails/")
page.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
reddit = etree.HTML(page.read())

# XPath expression : we get all links under body/p[2] containing *.htm
for node in reddit.xpath('/html/body/p[2]/a[contains(@href,".htm")]'):
    for i in node.items():
        url  = 'http://www.419scam.org/emails/' + i[1]
        page = opener.open(url)
        page.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

        lst = url.split('/')
        try:
            if lst[6]: # else it's a "month" link
                filename = '/tmp/' + url.split('/')[4] + '-' + url.split('/')[5]
                f = open(filename, 'w')
                f.write(page.read())
                f.close()
        except:
            pass

# vim:ts=4:sw=4
```

Comment: Now, I get all links and I save all the stuff in `/tmp/<DATE>`