# How can I download entire website using urlib?

Tags: python

I need to download entire websiteusing python urlib
like

```
import urllib

site = urllib.urlopen('http://www.mathrubumi.com/index.php')
site_data = site.read()
```

It downloads only the first page. That is index.php. How can I  make the code to download entire website. 
By looping ??
or Is there any other way?
For example in `wget` looping is not required in the code

```
wget \ --recursive \--no-clobber \ --page-requisites \ --html-extension \  --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \ --domains website.org \    --no-parent \    www.website.org/tutorials/html/
```

Comment: If by "entire website" you mean including pictures, stylesheets, etc., or even all other pages of the same domain, you should scan the page for links to those elements and download them recursively.

Comment: @tobias_k I need all the pages in the website . Like when I am trying to get using wget

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a python script that goes through the links on a page recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885708/write-a-python-script-that-goes-through-the-links-on-a-page-recursively)

Comment: @Torxed  It is not a duplicate. wget automatically create directories and store the html file

Comment: @karu Yes but your original question had nothing to do with `wget`, you asked if this is possible in Python (specificly with urllib) and it's **not**, however `BeautifulSoup` for instance has this feature, just like wget, scrapy and some others. But urllib doesn't and the duplicate link i gave you, shows you how to do it in `BeautifulSoup` (hate that name btw, long and bulky to write) :P

Comment: @Torxed. Yes, you are absolutely right. It is possible execute wget with python I know. But  I need other one

Comment: @karu you make no sense :P Check my link, `BeautifulSoup` is "other on".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to download a complete website with `urllib`, you'll have to parse every page, find all links and download them too. It's doable, but it can be tricky to get right.

I suggest you either look into [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) if you want a pure python solution or just [call `wget`](https://superuser.com/a/709680/553189) from your script.

Comment: But could you please write the code for scrapy that could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user (in another question asked but deleted because.. reasons..) pointed out references to using BeautifulSoup as an alternative, here's a working example to retrieve all `<a href="something.html">something</a>`               links and save them locally:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from os.path import basename

def store_links(page):
    with open(basename(page), 'wb') as fh:
        site = urllib.urlopen(page)
        site_data = site.read()

        fh.write(site_data)

        for link in BeautifulSoup(site_data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
            if link.has_attr('href'):
                store_links(link['href'])

store_links('http://www.nytimes.com')
```

Notice: Havn't tested, currently on a locked down machine so syntax errors might be expected, but the idea is the same:

1. Create a recursive function that will call itself whenever it finds a link
2. Give that recursive function a starting-point and let it go nuts

Comment: Hehe, i can correct them later this evening (once i'm on my private machine again, where i happen to have BeautifulSoup.. this was written out-of-my-mind-compilator) :P

Comment: Code can run without syntax errors but it is not  doing his task, I am sorry

Comment: What exactly is it that the code doesn't do? Doesn't do anything at all? :) As mentioned, can fix the minor errors later, try fiddling around with it because this is a 99% working concept, just some clitches most likely.

Comment: It will create one file with same name www.nytimes.com.  nothing else The file is empty

Comment: @karu Ok i'll get back to you and edit this solution within 4h (end of my shift)

Comment: It's probably a good idea to keep a list of pages already visited, or the script might never stop.

Comment: @DanielHepper Thought of that too but didn't bother writing the code, kept it "simple" as a proof of concept and not do the entire work for karu, but it struck me after posting it too :)

Comment: Yes, it is important.Other wise it is a non stop process.

Comment: @Torxed It is not an easy game .It is just like creating new wget

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are not using urlencode method then you could use urllib2 which allows you to set your headers and UA. Or you can use requests which supports more API. [See documentation here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)
2. To use urllib to download the entire website, the website must enable directory listing, for which most site owners will not allow by setting in the .htaccess.